# Why I can't call a method stored in parent UIViewController from embedded UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent ui view controller and it has a method responsible for printing data to the console:

```
func printSomeData() {
    print("printing some data")
}
```

It also has a container with embedded `UITableViewController`. The table itself has a pull to refresh functionality implemented and it prints the string when user pulls the table:

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    print("Refreshing!!")
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Now I want to call `printsomeData` from the `refresh` method.

This is what I try:

parent UIViewController:

```
class MainMenu: UIViewController, printing{

    func printSomeData() {
        print("some date")
    }

}
```

embedded UITableViewController:

```
protocol printing{
    func printSomeData()
}

class MainMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate: printing?

    func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("Refreshing!!")

    if let _ = delegate{
        delegate?.printSomeData()
    }


    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

But now when I pull the table I only see `Refreshing!!`, there is no way I could see `printing some data`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where are you assigning the delegate?**

And write the optional method call as a single line

```
delegate?.printSomeData()
```

or like that:

```
if self.delegate != nil {
    self.delegate!.printSomeData()
}
```

Inside `MainMenu`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // tableViewController is placeholder for `MainMenuTableViewController` reference
    tableViewController.delegate = self
}
```

If i have understand you correctly and the MainMenu has a ContainerView with MainMenuTableViewController than should this solve your problem:

```
class MainMenu: UIViewController, Printer {

    func printSomeData() {
        print("some date")
    }
}

protocol Printer {

    func printSomeData()
}

class MainMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var printer: Printer? {

        guard let printer = self.parentViewController as? Printer else {

            return nil
        }
        return printer
    }

    func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("Refreshing!!")

        printer?.printSomeData()

        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I changed `if let _ = delegate{
        delegate?.printSomeData()
    }` to `delegate?.printSomeData()`, but can you tell me how (and where) can I assign the delegate?

Comment: Thanks, but now `tableViewController.delegate = self` brings me the error saying: `use of unresolved identifier tableViewController`... How can I fix that?

Comment: rename the `tableViewController` to your tableView reference. May you can send a more detailed version of your code?

Comment: My problem is that I don't have any tableView reference here. I just added `var tableViewController:MainMenuTableViewController` but then I'm getting error that `class MainMenu has no initializers` and I'm not sure what am I missing...

Comment: I posted the latest version of my code, please check edit to my original question

Comment: check my last edit that should solve your problem, if not then you'll have to provide some informations about how the viewControllers are setup and nested

Comment: Thank you very much, that latest version of your code worked fine in my case!

Comment: May remove your edit on the main question to not leed other into wrong solutions 